# How to encode method parameters using HadoopRpcRequestProto request field in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, rpc, protocol-buffers

The Hadoop RPC engine uses Protocol Buffer to encode/decodes the bytes from the wire.

I am trying to invoke a method on a Hadoop Server using the HadoopRpcRequestProto

```
HadoopRpcRequestProto rpcReHadoopRpcRequestProtoquest;
    HadoopRpcRequestProto.Builder builder =   HadoopRpcRequestProto.newBuilder();
    builder.setMethodName("foo");
```

So if my "foo" method takes two parameters,
    foo(String name, int num);

How do I encode the parameters and set them to the HadoopRpcRequestProto's request field?

TIA

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do something like this:

```
private HadoopRpcRequestProto constructRpcRequest(Method method, Object paramObj) {
  HadoopRpcRequestProto rpcRequest;
  HadoopRpcRequestProto.Builder builder = HadoopRpcRequestProto
      .newBuilder();
  builder.setMethodName(method.getName());

  Message param = (Message) paramObj;
  builder.setRequest(param.toByteString());
  rpcRequest = builder.build();
  return rpcRequest;
}
```

For the `Message` class we are talking about `com.google.protobuf.Message`. I think you need to write a .proto file and compile it with `protoc` after to generate your Java bindings and you can then use it in your Java code. So for example a .proto file could look like this:

```
message Person {
  required int32 id = 1;
  required string name = 2;
  optional string email = 3;
}
```

And if you do `protoc myperson.proto` then this will generate a class called `MyPerson.java` which will have an inner class `Person` looking like this:

```
public static final class Person extends
  com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessage
  implements PersonOrBuilder {
   ...
}
```

This `GeneratedMessage` class extends from `AbstractMessage` which implements the `Message` interface I mentionned above. So basically you can create your `Person` object, and then you should be able to pass it using the `builder.setRequest(person.toByteString())` .

Comment: Thanks Charles. But I am still unclear on how to pack the method argument types and values into the paramObj.

Comment: @user2003006 I added some more details, you would need to either compile a proto file to create your classes, or create a class implementing the Message interface yourself.